# Formatting of pandas dataframes in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter

When I display a pandas dataframe in a Jupyter Notebook using, e.g. `df.head()`, I get a display with all white columns. However, on some websites I have seen them formatted with an alternating white and gray rows [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/). Is this possible inside the notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a recent change](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#table-style) in Jupyter's default table styling.  I saw this change in my own notebooks when I upgraded Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks. `$ conda update notebook` solved it. Appreciate it.