# Missing grid lines when displaying a dataframe in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm working on Jupyter notebook now, just learned to open a csv file with pandas.
However the guy in the video (who explains how to do it) has grids to separate things:
Here are screenshot of his screen and mine respectively:

[image]

[image]

I hope you understood what I meant, you'll see that grids are missing, I'm just curious where they are. It might not effect my work at Jupyter, but still however.

Comment: You have a newer version of Jupyter Notebook.  The table display interface was updated about a year ago into what you are seeing.

Comment: It's a difference in the html output pretty printing in Jupyter, there is probably a difference in the jupyter versions. Could you try `pd.set_option('display.html.table_schema', True)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not contain a actual coding issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting of Pandas Dataframes in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663070/formatting-of-pandas-dataframes-in-jupyter-notebook)