# Pandas Dataframe Display missing gridlines (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, display

For some reason, whenever I create a dataframe in pandas from reading in data from a file, I don't have gridlines:

[image: my_dataframe_display]

I have checked my settings for pd.options for all display attributes and everything was set to the default. Can anyone help me change the formatting of my dataframe? This format happens even when I open new python notebooks within jupyter notebook.

Comment: Did you try updating your JuPyter as suggested on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663070/formatting-of-pandas-dataframes-in-jupyter-notebook) similar post?

Answer (score 1):

Add this and run from a cell

```
%%HTML
<style type="text/css">
table.dataframe td, table.dataframe th {
    border: 1px  black solid !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

Use `df` instead of `print(df)`

*Source: answer by [MEdwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10100272/medwin) here [Python Jupyter Notebook print dataframe borders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51858584)*